# How can I get a list of events listeners available for an iframe?

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I have an iframe in my app. I want to see a list of all events available for this iframe.

I found a script on stackoverflow, with which I can get all events on window:

```
Object.keys(window).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on/.test(key)) {
        console.log('Event name: ' + key);
    }
});
```

I try it on my iframe:

```
Object.keys(document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on/.test(key)) {
        console.log('Event name: ' + key);
    }
});
```

I get no event.

So. I'm asking: How can I get a list of all events available for an iframe element ?

**Edit**: Just to be clear. I want the list of available events on the iframe, not on the iframe window...

By example, `onload` is an event available for an iframe and can be used. I want an entire list of available events on that iframe element.

I also try:

```
Object.keys(document.querySelector('iframe')).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on/.test(key)) {
        console.log('Event name: ' + key);
    }
});
```

No event show in my console.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No error.